# where is String.class in websphere

Tags: java, websphere

As we know, `String.class(java.lang.String)` is in `rt.jar`

But when I find `String.class` in websphere, I can't find `String.class` in `rt.jar`

Output:

> the websphere classloader log:
>   java.lang.String  无法获取文件名。这些文件通常是从 C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/jre/lib/ 装入的。

thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, WebSphere ships with an IBM JDK.  With an IBM JDK, you will find the java/lang/String class file in the vm.jar file.  For instance on my intel linux IBM JDK, java/lang/String.class is in the following two jars:

jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/jclSC180/vm.jar

jre/lib/amd64/default/jclSC180/vm.jar